# Clear a select Custom field based a selection from another field on update

Tags: groovy, jira

I have the following fields:

System,
CMS,
Aquarius,

I would like to clear the Aquarius field based on the system selection.  For example, a user.  Initially a user created an issue and For system they selected: CMS and completed a value "abcde" on the CMS field.

Now the user would like to update the issue. Now they select Aquarius, then complete the field the Aquarius field with the value "jklm".  When this happens, I would like to clear the values stored on the CMS field, so this field will not show on the View Screen.

Please note: These are single select fields.

Below is my code:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.option.LazyLoadedOption
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.DefaultIssueChangeHolder
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue

Issue issue = event.issue

def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def customField2 = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("System")
LazyLoadedOption systemOption = (LazyLoadedOption) issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField2)


def changeHolder = new DefaultIssueChangeHolder();
def customField4 = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects(issue).find {it.name == "Aquarius Category"}


if (systemOption?.getValue() == "CMS2") {
 customField4.updateValue(null, issue, new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField4), ""),changeHolder)
}
```

Unfortunately it's failing
Note: Using a custom listener - Scriptrunner

Answer (score 0):

You could use

issue.setCustomFieldValue(cf, null)
issueManager.updateIssue(user, issue, eventDispatch.Event_Type, boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work.  It was really a minor error. When setting the Value of a custom field. It's import to take not of the field type we are setting. For example when setting a Text Field we can use:

```
if (systemOption?.getValue() == "CMS2") {
 customField4.updateValue(null, issue, new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField4), ""),changeHolder)
}
```

But when setting a select (Dropdown) Field Type then we should use:

```
if (systemOption?.getValue() == "CMS2") {
 customField4.updateValue(null, issue, new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField4), null),changeHolder)
}
```

In summary null instead of ""